# Stemming on tokenized words

Tags: python, nlp, stemming

Having this dataset:

```
>cleaned['text']
0         [we, have, a, month, open, #postdoc, position,...
1         [the, hardworking, biofuel, producers, in, iow...
2         [the, hardworking, biofuel, producers, in, iow...
3         [in, today, s, time, it, is, imperative, to, r...
4         [special, thanks, to, gaetanos, beach, club, o...
                                ...                        
130736    [demand, gw, sources, fossil, fuels, renewable...
130737         [there, s, just, not, enough, to, go, round]
130738    [the, answer, to, deforestation, lies, in, space]
130739    [d, filament, from, plastic, waste, regrind, o...
130740          [gb, grid, is, generating, gw, out, of, gw]
Name: text, Length: 130741, dtype: object
```

Is there a simple way to stem all the words?

Comment: Do you mean taking `demand` and inferring English matches like `demanding`, `demanded`, `demands`, etc.?

Comment: As an example, the dataset contains the word "car" and "cars". I want them both to be the same.

Comment: What you ask for is difficult.  English doesn't have regular forms which easily permits that.  Look at some of the *related* links for this question for several approximations.

Comment: Actually, in R it is quite easy to do so I guess there is a way to do this. Baiscally, I guess such algorithms trim words with many letters in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find better answers but I personally find the `LemmInflect` library to be the best for lemmatization and inflections.

```
#!pip install lemminflect
from lemminflect import getLemma, getInflection, getAllLemmas

word = 'testing'
lemma = list(lemminflect.getAllLemmas(word, upos='NOUN').values())[0]
inflect = lemminflect.getInflection(lemma[0], tag='VBD')

print(word, lemma, inflect)
```

```
testing ('test',) ('tested',)
```

I would avoid stemming because it's not really useful if you want to work with language models or just text classification with any context. Stemming and Lemmatization both generate the root form of the inflected words. **The difference is that stem might not be an actual word whereas, lemma is an actual language word**.

Inflections are the opposite of a lemma.

---

```
sentence = ['I', 'am', 'testing', 'my', 'new', 'library']

def l(sentence):
    lemmatized_sent = []
    for i in sentence:
        try: lemmatized_sent.append(list(getAllLemmas(i, upos='NOUN').values())[0][0])
        except: lemmatized_sent.append(i)
    return lemmatized_sent

l(sentence)
```

```
['I', 'be', 'test', 'my', 'new', 'library']
```

```
#To apply to dataframe use this
df['sentences'].apply(l)
```

Do read the [documentation](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect) for LemmInflect. You can do so much more with it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have any idea about how to apply this to the whole column of lists?

Comment: updated my answer for a single sentence. You can create a function and apply it to the pandas column.

Comment: Do mark the answer if it solves your problem. thanks and good luck.

Comment: Thank you again. I can't edit the answer, but I think you should add getAllLemmas in import